# I'm struggling to understand why the last for loop is giving me such a hard time

Tags: python, read.csv

I am given a CSV file (influenza) to open and find the data that I want to process. I need to find the average activity level for the state of NC.

I can get the activity level and year extracted into a list, however, I want the last half of my code to find all activity levels for the "target_year" and remove the 'Level' in front of the number so that I can get the average.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('influenza (2).csv', 'r') as influenza_file:
    contents_1 = csv.reader(influenza_file)
    rows = []

    row_count = 1

    for row in contents_1:
        if 16259 <= row_count <= 16751:
            columns_selected = [row[3], row[7]]
            rows.append(columns_selected)

        row_count += 1
for row in rows:
    print(row)

target_year = ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22']

level_influenza = []

for year in target_year:
    for row in rows:
        if row[1] == year and row[0] == 'Level':
            level_influenza.append(row[0].replace('Level ', ''))

print(level_influenza)
```

So the year 2015-16 will have multiple entries for the activity level (1-13) and they will repeat and I want to store those entries into a list for that given year.

Sample output of what I have (keep in mind that this is much longer):

```
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 3', '2016-17']
['Level 4', '2016-17']
['Level 7', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 5', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 10', '2016-17']
['Level 5', '2016-17']
['Level 4', '2016-17']
['Level 2', '2016-17']
['Level 2', '2016-17']
['Level 3', '2016-17']
['Level 3', '2016-17']
['Level 2', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 1', '2016-17']
['Level 2', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
['Level 1', '2015-16']
...
```

Comment: You should provide a few sample lines of the CSV file so we can run the code.  That said, `row[0] == 'Level'` means **matches exactly** but the .replace implies you expect something like `'Level 1'` so it will never be true.

Comment: Right.  You want something like `... and "Level' in row[0]` or `row[0].startswith('Level')`.

Comment: I was able to answer with "row[0].startswith('Level')" but I want to identify the year so that I can find the average of certain years. What changes can I make to do this?

Comment: You can use the `split` function to split a string into a list of strings. For example `'2016-17'.split("-")` would give `['2016', '17']`.